# Made a "safety" wrapper for dict get command, but can't make it work

Tags: tcl

I was getting tired of using `dict exists` to protect against runtime error when using the `dict get` command, so I wrapped `dict get` in a "safe" version of itself.  But, I can't figure out why it doesn't work.  The dict exists command does not seem to accept the way I'm parameterizing the keys.  I didn't expect to run into any problems doing something so simple, but I must be making a stupid mistake.  Here is the code:

```
#====================================================================================================
# dictGet
#
#   Desc:   Safe version of "dict get".  Checks to make sure a dict key exists before attempting to
#           retrieve it, avoiding run-time error if it does not.
#   Param:  dictName    -   The name of the dict to retrieve from.
#           keys        -   List of one or more dict keys terminating with the desired key from
#                           which the value is desired.
#   Return: The value of the dict key; -1 if the key does not exist.
#====================================================================================================
proc dictGet {theDict keys} {
    if {[dict exists $theDict [split $keys]]} {
        return [dict get $theDict [split $keys]]
    } else {
        return -1
    }
}

#====================================================================================================
#Test...
dict set myDict 0 firstName "Shao"
dict set myDict 0 lastName "Kahn"

puts [dictGet $myDict {0 firstName}]
```

Comment: Use `{*}$keys` instead of `[split $keys]`.

Comment: Thank you.  That worked when I compiled it online, but wasn't working in Eclipse for some reason.  After some googling, I found this is called the "expand" operator.  Any insight as to why the interpreter can't recognize the individual items in the list until I expand the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `split` command doesn't change the number of words in the place where the keys should be. If you split the list `{0 firstName}`, you still have the list `{0 firstName}` as result. To get individual keys, expand the list with `{*}`.

```
set theDict {0 {firstName foo} 1 {firstName bar}}
# -> 0 {firstName foo} 1 {firstName bar}
set keys {0 firstName}
# -> 0 firstName
list dict exists $theDict [split $keys]
# -> dict exists {0 {firstName foo} 1 {firstName bar}} {0 firstName}
list dict exists $theDict {*}$keys
# -> dict exists {0 {firstName foo} 1 {firstName bar}} 0 firstName
```

Also, if you use this:

```
proc dictGet {theDict args} {
```

you can invoke the command like this:

```
dictGet $myDict 0 firstName
```

You still need to expand `$args`, but at least to me it seems like a good idea to use a invocation that looks like the standard `dict get` invocation.

Documentation: [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [{*}](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Comment: Great answer and I like the bit about using args to make the invocation more natural.